# How to write CSS code for a nested element?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="button share" style="display: none; float: left" id="share_btn_cont">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="share_btn" id="share_btn" style="width:800px; display: block;">Share on Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Here's my code for a Facebook share button. I've added some styling to the `<a>` element. I'd like to know how to write the CSS code for it in the parent file. How do I call out the `<a>` element?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Unclear question. Post some question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` has a class. Just target the class?

```
.share_btn {
   //styling goes here
}
```

Comment: I tried

.share_btn {
 width: 800px;
 display: block;
}

It didn't work.

Comment: Then you have other styles overriding that one. Provide a link to the page, or learn how CSS works (Cascading style sheets) - you can find out which rules override the one you made if you look at the element in the browser's developer view, or install something like Firebug in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write styles in an external css file for all buttons inside the div,

```
.button.share a.share_btn {
    // Add styles here;
}
```

You could add just `a.share_btn`, but this will apply to all `<a>` tags with the class.

If you want styles to be added to just this button, inside this only this div,

```
#share_btn_cont #share_btn {
    // Add styles here;
}
```

You can use `#share_btn_cont > a#share_btn`, but this will only look for elements which are one level down.

```
<div id="share_btn_cont"><a id="share_btn">Some Stuff</a></div>
```

It will work for the above case, and not for the one below.

```
<div id="share_btn_cont"><p><a id="share_btn">Some Stuff</a></p></div>
```

Also, use classes for a general use case, use id for targeting only a particular element.

Comment: None of this is working :(
It's working if I make the changes in the html file. But not in the css file.

Comment: have you included the css file using <link href="`path of file`">?

Comment: add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css/file" type="text/css">

Answer (score -1):

```
.parent:first-child {
    //code
}
```

Comment: .button_share:a {
 width: 800px;
 display: block;
}

Didn't work.

Comment: `.button_share:first-child { width: 800px; display: block; }`

Comment: Something gonna wrong. Here everything working exellent http://codepen.io/powro01/pen/kkmOxv

Comment: It's working if I add the style changes in the html file. But not in the css file :(